# Grails databinding doubt

Tags: data-binding, grails

```
   Class Carro {
String name
String marca
String matricula

} 

Class CarroMovel{

String pro1
String prop2
String prop3

Carro carro

static hasMany = [ carros: Carro]

}
```

---

```
 def save2 = {

                def carroInstance = new Carro()
                def carroMovelInstance = new CarroMovel()

                carroInstance.name = params.name
                carroInstance.marca = params.marca
                carroInstance.matricula = params.matricula

                carroMovelInstance.prop1 = params.carroMovel.prop1
                carroMovelInstance.prop2 = params.carroMovel.prop2
                carroMovelInstance.prop3 = params.carroMovel.prop3

                carroInstance.save()
                carroMovelInstance.carro = carroInstance
                carroMovelInstance.save()                 

            }
```

The CarroInstance is saving, but the carroMovelInstance isn't. I cannot figure it out. Any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Grooveek is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046671/grails-databinding-doubt/6046780#6046780) in that you haven't ever invoked `carroMovelInstance.save()`.

However, it might be simpler for you to simply take advantage of Grails' databinding, instead of unnecessarily creating the associations and manually binding the parameters.

```
// Update your Carro domain.
def Carro {
    String name
    String marca
    String matricula

    // will cause persistence operations to cascade from CarroMovel to Carro
    static belongsTo = CarroMovel
}

// Update your save2 action.
// By passing 'params' to the CarroMovel constructor, Grails will bind request
// parameters to domain properties of the same name; it even works with associations!
def save2 = {
    def carroMovelInstance = new CarroMovel(params)
    if(carroMovelInstance.validate) {
        carroMovelInstance.save()
    }
}
```

Read up on Grails [Data Binding](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.6%20Data%20Binding), particularly the parts about associations. Additionally, read ["Understanding Cascading Updates and Deletes"](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.3.3%20Understanding%20Cascading%20Updates%20and%20Deletes) to understand how a call to `save()` on a parent domain object will (or will not) cascade to an associated domain object.

Answer (score 1):

you never ask for the carroMovelInstance to save... The carro instance has nor reference to carroMovel instance so there is no cascading of saving

Comment: I copied it wrongly. Last line should be :"carroMovelInstance.save()"